# User interface choice for managing an "orders" table

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-interface, user-experience

I'm using VB Net, but this is entirely a question about user interface, not coding.

I want to "manage" a table of "orders." Orders is a typical table with a foreign key pointing to a customer, and a one-to-many relationship with a "details" table. To manage orders means to enter new orders, add details to orders, record payments, print a list of orders, cancel orders, mark orders shipped, print one order, etc., etc. These tasks can be divided into tasks that affect single orders (cancel an order) and tasks that affect multiple orders (print a list of orders).

That task division led me to this user interface: present a form/window that displays by default a list of orders, and provide a button that switches the view from list mode to single-order mode. Each mode then provides the buttons for its tasks.

I first implemented this with panels, putting the controls for each view into its own panel, and then superimposing the panels. I then use hide and show methods to switch between panels, effectively switching between views. It works, but meh...

Would it be better to use a tabbed control, and put each view on its own tab? I'm not trying to re-invent any wheels. I know nobody gets fired for making it look like a Microsoft app. LOL :) But I haven't seen any retail applications to copy from.

Comment: Perhaps better asked on http://ui.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oded, thanks, I was not aware of that site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd argue that your "multiple panels" approach IS tabs, just without the tab part. In reality, tab controls do basically what you've already done with code, they just hide that behind a convenient design time facade.

Still, it's the same thing.

E James answer is pretty good. Would it make sense to put both on screen at a time? is this a touch screen app or a traditional windows app? How sophisticated is the target user?

Those are a few questions that should drive how complex you let the screen get.

Comment: It's a traditional windows desktop app. The list and the "invoice" single-record format might fit together if the list had fewer columns, but even then, it would be a pretty busy screen. I think I'll go with the tab control because, like you say, I'm just redoing the behavior using panels. Thanks for the input to you and E. James. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have room to show the list *and* all of the possible controls? If so, I would start with all controls disabled. When you select a single order, only the single order controls would be enabled, and when you select multiple orders, only the multiple orders controls would be enabled.

I would also put the most common tasks right into the list, if possible, so that only one click is required for frequent tasks.

Comment: Sure, the controls are just 5 or 6 buttons at the most. But there isn't room for both a list and a single record view. But you're giving me the idea of just having a list and then enabling and disabling the buttons according to whether single or multiple records are selected. That sounds like a possible alternative.